# Create your own n-qubit quantum gate in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I need to create the 2-qubit gates that are not supported by Qiskit (Ex: Controlled - F gate). Is there any way to create a class/object and use it as other basic gates?

Example:

```
qc = qiskit.QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cf(0, 1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

def cf(circuit, qubit1, qubit2):
    # Create a circuit that is equivalent to your gate:
    qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
    qc.cx(0, 1)
    qc.csx(1, 0)
    qc.cx(0, 1)

    # Convert the circuit to a gate:
    sr_swap = qc.to_gate(label = '√SWAP')

    # Add the gate to your circuit which is passed as the first argument to cf function:
    circuit.append(sr_swap, [qubit1, qubit2])

# We need this line to add the method to QuantumCircuit class:
QuantumCircuit.cf = cf
```

Now, you can use `cf` as other `QuantumCircuit` gates:

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.cf(0, 1)
circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's work!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a circuit that implements the gate you want and then convert that circuit to a gate. Once you have that gate, you can append it to other circuits. For example, you can do the following:

```
cf = QuantumCircuit(2)
cf.unitary(mat, [0, 1])
cf_gate = cf.to_gate()
```

Where `mat` is the unitary matrix that represents the effect of the controlled $F$ gate (or any other gate you want).
`cf_gate` will be a [`Gate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.html) as you wanted, and you can append it to other circuits as follows:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(cf_gate, [0, 1])
```